# how to call a jQuery function by clicking all link tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script>
    var init = function() {
        // Resize the canvases)
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            var s = "snowfall" + i
            var canvas = document.getElementById(s);
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            // Now the emitter
            var emitter = Object.create(rectangleEmitter);
            emitter.setCanvas(canvas);
            emitter.setBlastZone(0, -10, canvas.width, 1);
            emitter.particle = snow;
            emitter.runAhead(60);
            emitter.start(30);
        }
        $("canvas").delay(10000).animate({
            opacity: '0',

        });
    };
</script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="fst"><a href="#" data-href="Home"><span class="icon-menu" /> Home</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="fst"><a href="#" id="flip" data-href="AboutUs"><span class="icon-menu" /> About us</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="fst"><a href="#" data-href="Products"><span class="icon-menu" /> Products</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="fst"><a href="#" data-href="Franchising"><span class="icon-menu" /> Franchising</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="fst"><a href="#" data-href="News"><span class="icon-menu" /> News</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to use this jQuery code to all href tabs.

I tried to use the `click` function, in that case only the first tab works well, the rest don't work at all.

Can any one explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).data('href');

    // do whatever you need
});
```

Comment: Hello @Petar Vasilev.. I used the class name as navbar-nav for all anchor tags as You mentioned..but it does not works

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @Petar Vasilev's answer

http://jsfiddle.net/dHR8V/2/

```
$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  debugger;

  window.location.href = "someurl";

  // do whatever you need
});
```

When you click a link the handler captures the click event and is executed. You now have control of whatever happens when a link is clicked.